# How to put a check mark symbol next to the `main` text of an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I wonder how to put a check mark symbol in parentheses i.e., (`symbol(("\326"))`) next to the main text of an R plot's `main` argument?

```
plot(1:10, main = paste("bbb", bquote(symbol(("\326")))), col.main = 2)
```

Comment: Do you want to bold the symbols or 'bbb'.  Perhaps `plot(1:10, main = bquote(bold("bbb"~symbol(("\326")))), col.main = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need `paste` with `bquote`.  When we use `paste` with `bquote`, it is converting it to literal strings and the evaluation is not happening.  Instead, pass the string "bbb" inside the `bquote` and use connectors (`~`) to add a space

```
plot(1:10, main = bquote("bbb"~symbol(("\326"))), col.main = 2)
```

[image]

---

Another option if we need `paste` is `expression`

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(paste("bbb ", symbol(("\326")))), col.main = 2)
```

Comment: @Reza An option with `tidyverse` would be `pivot_longer(f, cols = -id) %>% count(id, name, value) %>% filter(n == 1) %>% select(-n) %>% group_by(id, name) %>% filter(n() == 1)`

Comment: Arun, I'm sure yo'll like this [data.frame question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885625/class-changes-from-data-frame-to-integer-after-na-removal-in-r)?